# create array using each class name

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I'm trying to create an array by accessing a class called 'name'. However, I'm only able to get the list of names in one block when I alert the array. I think I may be using the .each() wrong. I want to return an array that has the names listed separately. I would greatly appreciate any help!
[image: html]

```
jquery

    $('.dropdown-content ul li span').click(function(){
        $('.hiddenfield').val($(this).html());
            $('form').submit(function(){
            var arr=[];
            $('.name').each( function()
                arr.push(('.dropdown-content').val($(this).text()));
                alert(arr);
            })
    });
    });
```

Comment: Please post real code.... not images of code. How is anyone supposed to be able to copy code from an image to try to help you?

Comment: Why is `submit` nested inside `click`?

Comment: Missing `$` in `arr.push(('.dropdown-content')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two Problems:**

1. The `submit` event handler should not be nested inside the `click` handler. This will bind a new `submit` event on the form each time `<li>` is clicked.
2. Syntax Errors highlighted in the code below

**Code:**

```
$('.dropdown-content ul li span').click(function () {
    $('.hiddenfield').val($(this).html());
});

$('form').submit(function () {
    var arr = [];
    $('.name').each(function () { // <-- Missed { here
        arr.push($('.dropdown-content').val($(this).text()));
        //       ^        Missed `$` here
        alert(arr);
    });
});
```

---

To get the array of text, you can use [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) with [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

```
var arr = $('.name').map(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()); // Use trim to remove leading and trailing spaces
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you explain what .get() does in this case?

Comment: Welcome @st4rgut. `get()` return an array from jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following using `map()` function. Separate the `click` and `submit` event.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var arr=[];
    var arr = $('.name').map( function()
        return $(this).text();              
    }).get();
    alert(arr);
});

$('.dropdown-content ul li span').click(function() {
    $('.hiddenfield').val($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: returns a jQuery object not an array